# Are the Platonic solids shadows of 4-polytopes?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry

Say that a *3D shadow* of a 4-polytope is a parallel projection to 3-space, not necessarily orthogonal to that 3-space (that would make it an orthogonal projection).
I am wondering if each of the five regular polyhedra in 3D are shadows of regular 4-polytopes.
The 4-simplex can project to a regular tetrahedron, the tesseract to a cube, [the 16-cell can parallel project to a cube or a regular octahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/16-cell).  But I do not know if the 120-cell can project to a regular dodecahedron, or if the 600-cell can project to a regular icosahedron.  (I think not?)  Perhaps under perspective projection they can?  Failing that, perhaps irregular convex 4-polytopes have the regular dodecahedron and icosahedron as shadows?

I am not as familiar with the regular 4-polytopes as I should be; otherwise the answers would be evident.  I am sure those more knowledgeable can answer my question easily.  Thanks!

**Addendum**. The confusion in my question (sorry!) caused a confusing welter of comments (some now deleted), but I think matters are clearer now.  Three of the Platonic solids can be achieved as parallel-projection shadows
(light at $\infty$): tetrahedron, cube, octahedron.
As Theo explains in his answer, the dodecahedron and icosahedron cannot be so achieved.
However, the dodecahedron can be achieved as a perspective-projection shadow (light at a finite point).
The analogy with 3D is as follows.  If a light is placed close to a face of the dodecahedron, a pentagon shadow results.  Similarly, if a light is placed close to dodecahedral facet of the 120-cell, a dodecahedral shadow results (as Theo says).

What remains unclear to me is if the icosahedron can be achieved as a shadow.  If one could place the light directly on a vertex of the 600-cell, then the shadow should be its vertex figure, which is an icosahedron.  But if the light is exterior to the polytope, the shadow is more complicated.

Comment: I don't see the logic of this question.  In 2-dim, how is a regular pentagon a projection of a regular 3-dim polytope (say icosahedron would be a natural candidate)?  Similarly, why would you expect an icosahedron to be a projection of a 600-cell?  Not at all!  

Comment: A pentagonal prism has a regular pentagon as a projection. I suppose there is some (irregular, convex) 4-polytope that is to the regular dodecahedron or icosahedron as the pentagonal prism is to the pentagon. 

Comment: http://www.georgehart.com/rp/120-cell.gif

Comment: @Igor: Perhaps you are right, there is little logic here. However, a regular pentagon is a shadow of a dodecahedron from a light just above one face. @Agol: Yes, that is a beautiful construction! But I am unclear if it is a "shadow."

Comment: @Igor: I was imagining three types of shadow projection: orthogonal, parallel, and perspective, with the latter corresponding to light at a
point.  And wondering which is needed to obtain the Platonic solids.
So your answer that the regular icosahedron is a perspective shadow but not a parallel shadow is what I was seeking.  So: Thanks! And apologies for the lack of clarity.

Comment: [I don't think Gerry meant to imply that the pentagonal prism is a regular polytope!]

Comment: @Igor, give me some credit here, I know very well that a pentagonal prism is not a regular polytope. You will note that OP was willing to settle for irregular convex 4-polytopes, so I motivated my answer by pointing to an irregular convex 3-polytope. @Joseph, thanks. You refer to Igor's answer about perspective shadows, etc., but that answer must itself be in a deep shadow, as I can't see it anywhere. 

Comment:  @Joseph-O-Rourke, in your edited addendum, you accidentally use the word "triangle" to refer to the first Platonic solid in $3$-d space ($\mathbb{R}^3$), when I'm certain that you meant to type the word "tetrahedron".

Comment: @Joseph-O'Rourke, I must admit that I don't completely follow your distinction between an orthogonal projection and parallel projection from 4-space onto 3-space. Would you mind specifying or explaining it with a bit more detail? Say that I have an object in 4-space bounded withinn [1,2] in each of the four dimensions. For a point light source, What coordinate $A$ in 4-space would end up giving you a orthog. projection onto the 3-space {x,y,z,0}, and what coordinate $B$ for the light source would give you a parallel projection on the same 3-space {x,y,z,0}? Is a receiving 3-d surface needed? 

Comment: I guess a receiving 3-d surface is not needed.  Specifying a 3-d "volume" slice of 4-space is sufficient to define which region of the shadow being cast is being specified.  Is the *parallel shadow* the shadow cast by a point light source which is within the 3-space {x,y,z,0}, and an *orthogonal shadow* cast by a point light source in $\mathbb{R}^4$ which is not in the  $\mathbb{R}^3$ region {x,y,z,0}?

Comment: @sleepless: In parallel projection, the rays are parallel but they may strike the shadow plane/flat at an angle different from 90 deg.  In orthogonal projection, the rays are parallel and strike the projection plane/flat orthogonally. If the projection 3-flat is {x,y,z,0}, then orthogonal
projection occurs when the light is at {x,y,z,oo}.

Answer (score 7):

Joseph, in your response to Igor in the comments you allow holding the candle that's casting the shadow very close to a face.  This is precisely the picture that Ian gave in the comments.  But in your question you require that the candle be infinitely far away, so that it is a parallel projection.  If you do allow holding the candle very close to a face, then it suffices to find a 4-tope that has your given 3-tope as a face, and the 600-cell has 20-cell faces and the 120-cell has 12-cell faces.

But if you require your candle to be infinitely far away, I think you're hosed.  From three to two, the face-centered shadows of the dodecahedron and icosahedron are, respectively, the regular 10- and 6-gons, for example.  Similarly, any parallel shadow of the 120 or 600 cell will look like some sort of "equator", which you can see will have many too many facets to be an icosahedron or a dodecahedron.  For example, [here](http://mathforum.org/pcmi/hstp/sum2007/photos/PCMI2007028.jpg)'s a parallel projection orthogonal to a face of the 120 cell.

Comment: The 600-cell has 4-cell (tetrahedron) faces. 

Comment: Who is Ian, and where is his comment? Has that, too, fallen into a shadow? 

Comment: @Theo: As Tom mentions, I think you meant that the _vertex figure_ of a 600-cell is a 20-face cell (in fact, an icosahedron).

Comment: @Gerry: I believe "Ian" = "Ian Agol" = "http://mathoverflow.net/users/1345/agol".

Comment: @Tom: Oops, yes. Anyway, some shadow of the 600 cell is the 20-cell --- the shadow that Wikipedia uses for its picture on "600 cell". But this is a shadow with the candle close to the object. @Gerry: Sorry, I meant Ian Agol's comment to the original post; my answer started out as a comment.

Comment: @Theo: I feel you must be right, but there remains an aspect of the 600-cell I don't understand.  Wikipedia labels what you pointed to as the _Schlegel diagram_ of
the 600-cell.  But the Schlegel diagram is the view from just outside
one facet, and so is a subdivision of that facet.  I cannot reconcile the image identified as the Schlegel diagram of the 600-cell with the definition of the Schlegel diagram http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlegel_diagram.

Comment: The two wikipidia pages contradict each other-- either the definition of Schlegel diagram is wrong, or the 600-cell picture isn't a Schlegel diagram  (or both).  In any case, that shadow is what you get when the candle is just outside a vertex (exactly analogous to @TomGoodwillie's description of the "20-hedron corner view poking you in the eye"), so doesn't that picture complete the answer to the question?

Comment: The picture link seems to be broken and I did not find it [in the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20230000000000*/http://mathforum.org/pcmi/hstp/sum2007/photos/PCMI2007028.jpg), either. But since the filename is the same, I guess it might be this picture: https://projects.ias.edu/pcmi/hstp/sum2007/photos/PCMI2007028.jpg - as I wasn't absolutely sure, I posted just a comment instead of editing. (Sorry for a comment on an old post - but since the question was bumped, I checked whether some of the links here cannot be fixed.)

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, here's a non-answer all about the case of 3 projected to 2. i never thought all of this through before. For each of the five Platonic solids you can ask what do you see if you look at it from a face direction or from a corner direction. The answer usually depends on how far away it is. (I'm thinking of an eyeball instead of  light source, so "what you see from there" rather than "what the shadow looks like".) Taking the obvious ones first, we have:

4-hedron face or corner view: Always a regular 3-gon

6-hedron face view or 8-hedron corner view: Always a regular 4-gon

8-hedron face view: From infinitely far, a regular 6-gon. From large finite distance, a 6-gon with all sides equal but only regular 3-gon symmetry. At a certain distance (namely where you suddenly can see only 1 face rather than 1+3) a regular 3-gon, and so it remains until it hits you like a cream pie.

6-hedron corner view: Ditto, except that the 6-gon doesn't turn into a 3-gon until the final moment when it pokes you in the eye.

12-hedron face view: Exactly like the 8-hedron face view, except change 6 to 10 and 3 to 5.

20-hedron corner view: Just like 6-hedron corner view ($\times \frac{5}{3}$) except that the 10-gon does not wait until the final moment to become a 5-gon.

20-hedron face view: Always has at least the symmetry of a regular 3-gon. Initially a regular 6-gon, then an irregular 6-gon with equal sides, then suddenly the angles reverse their direction of change. Passes through a regular 6-gon again, then back to an irregular 6-gon and eventually turns into a regular 3-sided cream pie.

12-hedron corner view: Always has at least the symmetry of a regular 3-gon. Initially a 12-gon with the symmetry of a regular 6-gon, equal angles but not equal sides. Then an irregular 12-gon with merely 3-gon symmetry. For one moment a 6-gon (not regular, I'm sure) then an irregular 9-gon until it pokes you in the eye.

I don't know what the corresponding story is for the thing whose faces are 600 4-hedra, or the thing whose faces are 120 12-hedra. I started thinking about the thing whose faces are 24 8-hedra.

Comment: Ha! I like the "pokes you in the eye" characterization! The hexagon from one point above a vertex of a dodecahedron is interesting. I believe its edge lengths are in the golden ratio: three =1, three =1.618?

Comment: Cream pies, eye pokes... is this mathematics or a Three Stooges short?

Comment: I think it's what Reader's Digest would call "More Picturesque Speech". Obviously don't try it at home without protective goggles.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of the regular icosahedron, the natural source dimensionality is six, not four. In six dimensions integer lattice points may be rendered with icosahedral symmetry, as with the set of twenty points described in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4509280/248217). This symmetry enables anatural projection into an icosahedron in three dimensions.